# OpenCL on CPU Device - what happens under the hood?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencl, cpu, cpu-cores

So if I run an openCL Kernel function on a CPU device and *not* a GPU device, does the kernel automatically make use of all the cores on the CPU? For instance my system says I have 4 cores on the CPU will the kernel make use of all 4 cores automatically?

If the above is true, then does it mean that running an openCL kernel on a single CPU device would be equivalent to using standard std::threads (assuming we're using C++) to carry out the same tasks?

I ask because on my current computer openCL seems to only be able to access one CPU and no GPUs. So if I were to use openCL to parallelize my code it seems like it might be overkill if it will essentially be doing the same thing as an std::thread based implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without actually having access to the OpenCL implementation that you are actually using, it's hard to say exactly how it is implemented. I'm sure that there are more than one method of solving this problem (somewhat depending on the OS and other factors), but the most likely scenario is that it uses the threading system of the host OS in some way or another. OpenCL implementations are typically not written in C++, so it may not be `std::threads`, but almost certainly the same fundamentals that are the basis for `std::threads` on that system.

The purpose/benefit of using OpenCL when you have only a CPU device available would be that you can transparently transition from such a system to one that has a GPU device, without having two different sets of code.

It is also a little less difficult to debug OpenCL kernels that misbehave in this environment (I said less difficult, not easy, for a reason, before anyone complains) - assuming of course that the behaviour is the same in both environments, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I made the comparison with std::threads I didn't necessarily mean to imply that I thought they were literally the same under the hood, but rather was simply wondering if a single kernel call to a single CPU device would implicitly make use of all of the cores in the CPU in the same way that explicitly creating N std::threads would.

Comment: Sure, I didn't think you meant that, I was just making sure someone reading the answer would understand that too.

Comment: The parallelism provided by OpenCL goes beyond the one provided by `std::thread` because of vectorization. OpenCL work items on CPU are *not* threads, they are SIMD lanes.

Comment: @Cicada: Ehm, that clearly depends on the exact implementation of the CL compiler (I work with the implementation of OpenCL for ARM, so although I don't know much about how other companies implement OpenCL, I have a fair understanding of how our implementation works). When possible, the CL implementation may indeed auto-vectorize code that doesn't already use the vector types provided by the CL C language. But it is by no means guaranteed by the specification of OpenCL itself that it has to do so.

Comment: @Mats I knew someone would nitpick on this :)

Answer (score 2):

OpenCL SDK provided by Intel uses [tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb) under the hood. It's much more efficient than plain threads since it takes advantage of sophisticated scheduling and partitioning algorithms provided by TBB for better load balance and so better utilization of CPUs.